# Android : Compress images (PNG-JPG) without fully load them

Tags: android, image, compression

I'm searching for a library than can permit me to compress images file.

I tried to use Bitmap class, it works fine. But I think it's not a really efficiently alternative.

If you can help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

you can compress image by applying option like this

```
            Options options = new Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inScaled= true;

    Bitmap dummyBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageBitmapFilePath.get(position).getAbsolutePath(), options);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(dummyBitmap);
```

Comment: if you want to check the image height and width before loading it then  set inJustDecodeBounds option to true this will return  null bitmap but by using outHeight and outWidht option you can get the bitmap's height and width then compress that image by using above code and then again set inJustDecodeBounds optin to false so that you can get your compressed bitmap

Comment: It's not a compression - just resizing.

Comment: As Marek said, this is not an answer. The code is not compressing anything yet along compressing without decoding.